# Rendering two textures with blending and alpha test

Tags: opengl, textures, alphablending, alpha-transparency, blending

what I am looking for is the following... I have a circle on a square image, alpha is 0 at the corners

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1401029/circle.png

and also a *square* shadow, alpha is 0 everywhere else

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1401029/image.png

Well, I would like to have as final result a blending of these two renders, plus tha shadow not being rendered outside the circle

How could I achieve that? :)

Edit: this is my code so far (t2 circle, t1 shadow)

```
gl.glTexEnvf(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL2.GL_MODULATE);
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
gl.glAlphaFunc(GL2.GL_GREATER, 0.1f);
    t2.enable(gl);     
    t2.bind(gl);

    t2.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
    t2.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);

    a = 2.0f;
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(-a, -a, 0);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        gl.glVertex3f(-a, a, 0);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        gl.glVertex3f(a, a, 0);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(a, -a, 0);
    gl.glEnd();   

    t2.disable(gl);
gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_ALPHA_TEST);

gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc (GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    t1.enable(gl);
    t1.bind(gl);

    t1.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
    t1.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(-a, -a, 0);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        gl.glVertex3f(-a, a, 0);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        gl.glVertex3f(a, a, 0);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(a, -a, 0);
    gl.glEnd();   

    t1.disable(gl);
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

But it's not working so far, the shadow get completely rendered on the circle, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you will need to use multitexturing and modulate the second texture like [so](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/13114-lightmapping-with-opengl/). This like lightmapping, so the blending function (before the pixel gets blended with the framebuffer contents) is

```
output.rgb = Texture1.rgb * Texture2.rgb * 2;
output.a = Texture1.a * Texture2.a;
```

In Shawn Hargreaves' [words](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/08/04/dualtextureeffect.aspx),

"The easiest way to think about this operation is that the first texture defines the basic color of the object, which can then be adjusted by the second texture:

- Where the second texture contains 50% grey, the color is unchanged
- Where it is darker than 50%, the color is darkened
- Where it is brighter than 50%, the color becomes brighter
- If the second texture is not monochrome, the color is tinted accordingly"

This will make the circle texture the "mask" for the second texture (or vice versa).

Hope this helps!